# How can we loop through items, and download text files from a web site in bulk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-services

I am trying to figure out how to loop through items in a ListBox and download and bulk-download text files.

Here's the link that I'm looking at.

https://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/PWS/DownloadBulkData.aspx

I want to select this product.

'Call Reports -- Balance Sheet, Income Statement, Past Due -- Four Periods'

Then loop through years 2020-2012, and bulk-download these files to my local hard drive.

I hit F11 in my browser and easily found the button and the 'DatesDropDownList' but I don't see any URLs that link to the text files that are useful for doing all downloads.  Do you need Selenium for this?

As an alternative to selecting things in lists and clicking buttons, is there some kind of web service that makes this process easier?

Comment: Please [edit the question](/posts/65202606/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use selenium. Its a straightforward path to implement in Python what you manually do in a web browser.

Here's an example taken from what you've provided.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# using Google Chrome, can use the browser of your choice
driver = webdriver.Chrome('PATH/TO/chromedriver.exe')

url = 'https://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/PWS/DownloadBulkData.aspx'
driver.get(url)
```

Wait for available products to load, and then select value.

```py
path = "//select[@id='ListBox1']"
products = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, path)
    )
)

select = 'Call Reports -- Balance Sheet, Income Statement, Past Due -- Four Periods'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(path+"/option[text()='"+select+"']").click()
```

Wait for years to load. Get a list of the years. Select one of these as an example.

```py
path = "//select[@id='DatesDropDownList']"
dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, path)
    )
)

dates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(path+'/option')

# an example, you can loop through dates
driver.find_element_by_xpath(path+"/option[text()='"+dates[10].text+"']").click()
```

From here you could unzip the files, load them into a Pandas DataFrame, and then store in an Excel file, database, etc.

Comment: That looks much more elegant than what I thought it would.  I'll try to get the button click event going so I can do the download. Thanks so much!!!